# Visual Studio REST Unit Tests returning 404

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, http-status-code-404

Using the local development web server (Cassini) in Visual Studio 2012 I receive consistent 404 Not Found responses from an HttpClient during unit test execution. Hitting the same local URI in fiddler (or another REST client) produces a 200 OK response with the JSON I expected.

Any idea's why VS2012 would give different results? All of this testing is pointed to localhost until I can figure this out.

```
    [TestCategory("Cat 1")]
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTestMethod()
    {
        string id = "00000012";
        var client = new HttpClient( _server );

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.RequestUri = new Uri( String.Format("http://localhost:1234/api/GetDataById/{0}", id));
        request.Headers.Add( "apikey", "somekey" );
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;

        using ( HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync( request ).Result ) {
            Assert.IsNotNull( response.Content );
            Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK);
            Assert.AreEqual( "application/json", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType );
        }

        request.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Is the web application really started when the unit test runs? Are you using Test Explorer to run the test? Also, if you're using ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web API, there's no need to do http requests in unit tests; both frameworks are built for testability.

Comment: The web application is started. I'm using Resharper to run my Unit Tests. We are using Web API and have another set of unit tests to cover the controller. This set is geared towards testing the end-to-end round trip with authorization and header inspection.

Comment: If you debug the web application when R# runs a test and break in BeginRequest, is there something strange about the URL or anything else?

Comment: Yeah, that is the confusing part. Adding in a breakpoint right before the request is sent I can inspect the URL and it looks correct. In fact I can copy and paste it into fiddler and get a 200 OK response.

Comment: But if you try what I wrote?

Comment: Ran the web application in debug, and I put a breakpoint in Application_BeginRequest (which gets hit initially as the Web API help page loads. However running the R# unit tests the breakpoint does not get hit and the test completes with a 404.

Comment: Can you see in Fiddler where the request goes?

Comment: Fiddler picks up the initial WebAPI help page load but doesn't pickup the API request sent inside the test.  What does this mean? The request is getting filtered out at some level?